# SQL Query: For each item add multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, informix

How to write a SQl query to create "NewTable" using Table1 and Table2 which the result look like "NewTable" below ?

```
   Table1   
 EmmployeeID
|     1     |
|     2     |
|     3     |

  Table2
 AgencyID
|   a    |
|   b    |
|   c    |

              NewTable
      |EmmployeeID|AgencyID|
      |     1     |   a    |
      |     1     |   b    |
      |     1     |   c    |
      |     2     |   a    |
      |     2     |   b    |
      |     2     |   c    |
      |     3     |   a    |
      |     3     |   b    |
      |     3     |   c    |
```

Comment: Am I correct that you want to create a table with all possible cominations of EmmployeeID and AgencyID?

Comment: What database are you actually using here? Sometimes the syntax for SQL is slightly different, say, from Oracle to SQL Server to MySQL to Informix.  Mark only the database vendor that matters - it will help people give you a better answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the third table and then `INSERT` the values by doing a `CROSS JOIN` of `Table1` and `Table2`

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable
( 
  EmployeeID int,
  AgencyID varchar,
);

INSERT INTO NewTable
select EmployeeID, AgencyID
from Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my time.

Answer (score 1):

Combining two tables usually means a `JOIN`.

Generating every possible combination ("pairing") of rows usually means a "Cartesian product", also known as a `CROSS JOIN`, like this:

```
select EmployeeID, AgencyID
from Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
```

Comment: And in order to create the new table `CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE SELECT...`

Comment: Syntax for creating the new table is different for different vendors. Since OP specified 4 vendors, I asked him to clarify first...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable
select EmmployeeID,AgencyID 
from Table1,Table2
```

Comment: Using comma separated table names is not a great approach. It is much better to explicitly use a cross join. And of course depending on the actual DBMS this may or may not be valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CROSS APPLY` or `CROSS JOIN`. For example,

```
declare @a table (a int)
declare @b table (b char(1))

insert @a values (1),(2)
insert @b values ('a'),('b')

select * from @a cross apply @b order by a
```